# Background picture does not appear in the render?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm using Blender 2.74 and have added a picture as a background in the view , it is visible in the view but it doesn't appear in the render ,why is that ?
here is the picture

[image]

Many thanks,
Meri

Comment: please provide us with more information. [upload the blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and link it in your original post if you need to:

Comment: The picture is 2D http://az624219.vo.msecnd.net/media/1002/paddington_test.jpg

The pictures is 2D . Bhttp://az624219.vo.msecnd.net/media/1002/paddington_test.jpg

Blender 2.74 I am able to attach the pictures and I can see it but when I rendered I can't see anything. Why?

Many thanks, Meri

Comment: @Meri  how did you attach the picture ?, can add screenshots

Comment: I am going to Background images /add image/image and I open the folder where I have the picture

Comment: @Meri the background image in the 3d_view is for reference only( modeling reference) , it does not show up in the render

Comment: you have to use it as a texture for a plane (or other flat object) to be rendered

Comment: All right. Can you tell me how I can attach a picture that I can see? I understood. Many thanks

Comment: @Meri i'm writing the steps as an answer , bear with me

Answer (score 4):

the easy way is to enable the Addon that does exactly that :

- go to **File**➝ **User_Preferences**
- click on the **Addon** tab search for ***Import Image***,  check it and click **Save**

[image]

- go to **File** ➝**Import** ➝ **Import_Image_as_Plane**
- select your image  and click **Import**
- position your camera and render ( you may need to tweak light )

---

to setup easily the render after adding the image as plane :

- switch to **Cycles Render Engine**

[image]

- in 3d_view hit <kbd>Num 7</kbd> (this the top view)
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to set the camera in this view (you can move the camera up and down to fit the image )
- enable ***Ambient Occlusion***  in the **world** tab

[image]

- press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render

Comment: @Meri you are welcome , If you need more details I will add them