# How to add Image as object?

Tags: image

I am trying to find a way to import an image, so that I can use it for 2D animation. Is there any way to use an image so it imports as an object like a plane? Thanks!

Comment: see [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29015/5113)

Comment: @Chebhou arguably the answer to the other question should be the answer to this question here, and that other question should be directed here. this has a better tiitle, i think it will reach more people.